# Trying to restore data from new Postgres version to old Postgres version

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, pg-dump, pg-restore

I took a backup of the Postgres database version 15, and now I want to restore that data to Postgres version 13.1.2? is it possible?

Comment: What command line did you use?

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to downgrade PostgreSQL, no matter what.

The only way to success is the following cumbersome route:

- Take a plain-format dump with

  ```bash
  pg_dump -f dump.sql dbname
  ```

  You need to use `pg_dump` from version 15 for that
- Try to restore the dump to version 13 using `psql`. That will fail. Look at the error messages and edit `dump.sql`, manually changing the SQL syntax to avoid the error. Then try to restore again, and so on until all errors are gone.

I hope 13.1.2 is a typo, and you mean 13.12.

Comment: Thanks!

Yes, ```13.1.2``` was indeed a typo